# Como puedo aplicar este codigo de VBA a todos los libros de excel de una carpeta?

Tags: python, excel, vba, macros

tengo una carpeta con +300 libros de excel y a todos les tendria que ejecutar esta Macro. Existe la forma de realizarlo con algun codigo de VBA?

Muchas gracias y saludos!

```
Sub LimpiezaMesas()

    Range("F14") = "Circuito Electoral"
    Range("G14") = "Nro. Mesa"
    Range("H14") = "Inscriptos"

    Range("B10").Copy Range("F15:F26")
    Range("B7").Copy Range("G15:G26")
    Range("E10").Copy Range("H15:H26")
    
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Podrías dejarlo como un archivo VBS y ejecutarlo, incluyendo ahí mismo la lógica en VBA para recorrer cada workbook en la carpeta actual y haciendo eso que quieres hacer